# Jquery/php form have to click Submit Twice Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple form with jquery and php

whenever someone clicks the submit button they have to click it twice

Heres my jQuery

```
    $('#submit_btn').on('click', function(){
      var post_data, proceed, user_email, user_message, user_name, user_phone;

      user_name = $("input[name=name]").val();
      user_email = $("input[name=email]").val();
      user_phone = $("input[name=phone]").val();
      user_message = $("textarea[name=message]").val();
      proceed = true;
      if (user_name === "") {
        $("input[name=name]").css("border-color", "red");
        proceed = false;
      }
      if (user_email === "") {
        $("input[name=email]").css("border-color", "red");
        proceed = false;
      }
      if (user_phone === "") {
        $("input[name=phone]").css("border-color", "red");
        proceed = false;
      }
      if (user_message === "") {
        $("textarea[name=message]").css("border-color", "red");
        proceed = false;
      }
      if (proceed) {
        post_data = {
          userName: user_name,
          userEmail: user_email,
          userPhone: user_phone,
          userMessage: user_message
        };
        $.post("contact_me_test.php", post_data, (function(response) {
          var output;
          if (response.type === "error") {
            output = "<div class=\"error\">" + response.text + "</div>";
          } else {
            output = "<div class=\"success\">" + response.text + "</div>";
            $('#contact-form-container').fadeOut(function(e){
              $('#form-success-message').fadeIn();
            });
            $("#contact_form input").val("");
            $("#contact_form textarea").val("");
          }
          $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }), "json");
      }
    });
```

Heres my jQuery

Is there something that requires to thing to be pressed twice here?  I looked around online for hours and some people were saying you need to take the validation out of it but I've tried that and i get the same results.

Everything regarding the form is working fine the only thing is that you have to click TWICE

Comment: I wonder where the `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` is.

Comment: @DOCASAREL sorry i added those in later in an attempt to try to fix the problem based on stuff i read on line

Comment: Maybe an issue with the default action of the button? Try passing the event in your function and preventing the default.

Comment: `preventDefault()` doesn't seem to be the problem, because if that was the problem the page would be redirected to the target, which it is not!

Comment: you guys can check out the form on urbanfutsal.la/free_agents.html

Comment: For me it works ( sorry for spamming ; ).

Comment: did you have to click the button once or twice???  If ONCE what browser and operating system are you on?

Comment: The problem is not with the posted code.. when you look at `all.js` on his page you see the click handler assigned twice to the same id button.

Comment: @A1rPun i dont believe thats the issue...i did that because i read somewhere that you shouldn't put the validations inside the click handler and that might be the reason....but that did not work either

Comment: Just place some breakpoints in it and see what happens. If you can extract your problem in a fiddle we have someting to work with instead of your live website.

Comment: a recomendation: hide submit button after receiving the success message in order to avoid other innecessary click on submit button

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
$('#submit_btn').on('click', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  ... //Rest of code 
}
```

Comment: can you show me in an example on how your doing that